# Is there any good Markdown Javascript library or control?

Tags: javascript, controls, markdown

I want to build a site where the user can enter text and format it in Markdown. The reason I'd like a Javascript solution is because I want to display a live preview, just like on StackOverflow.

My site is not targeted at developers, however, so an editor control would be ideal.

I gather that on StackOverflow, the WMD editor is being used.

A quick search on Google also turns up Showdown library, which I think is actually being used by WMD.

Are there any other options? Are WMD/Showdown great tools already? What have been your experiences with the different options?

Comment: https://github.com/nhn/tui.editor

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you're not averse to using Ajax to generate the live preview, then another option is [markItUp!](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/). markItUp! is a universal markup-editor, and very flexible. It does provide 
an easy way of creating a markup editor, but unlike WMD, it doesn't provide its own live preview.

I used markItUp!, along with a simple JSP (using [MarkdownJ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/markdownj/)) for one of my open-source projects (a [Markdown plugin](http://github.com/myabc/roller-markdown/tree/master) for [Roller](http://roller.apache.org/)). If you're using another server-side technology, replace that simple JSP as appropriate.

I actually starting using this before I came across WMD. I'd agree, WMD is great, but has only just been open-sourced and is, at this stage, more difficult to customize the behavior of.

Answer (score 66):

We've been pretty happy with WMD. There are a few niggling bugs in it, however. Nothing major, but I would *love* if John Fraser (the author) made the code open source so we can fix some of them. He's promised to do so but other real life projects are getting in the way.

<s>I do follow up with John every week. I'll post on the blog once the WMD source is finally available.</s> Haven't been able to contact John Fraser in over a year now.

We have open sourced both the JavaScript Markdown library

http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

and the server-side C# Markdown library

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jeff. I didn't even realize WMD wasn't open source... I'll keep my eyes peeled.

Comment: What did you do about the gaping security hole?
For example:
<div onmouseover="alert('hi');">hi</div>

The above works in the WMD demo!

Comment: @superjoe30 That stuff is filtered on the server.

Comment: @superjoe30: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95821/markdownsharp-not-a-complete-rip-from-stack-overflow -- the same applies to the JavaScript version

Comment: Is PageDown still maintained? Will it be moving to GitHub now that Google Code is shutting down?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat looking at http://stackexchange.github.io/ you can see that it's in the list and last commit was 6 months ago (2015 already).

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend [marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked), which is lightweight, efficient, easy to use and supports GitHub Flavored Markdown (GFM) as well. It can be used in either server(nodejs) or client(browser) sides.

Comment: marked is still being developed and the minimized version is only 23 KB large.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know there really isn't any other browser-based editor for Markdown, at least none as extensive as the WMD editor.

Showdown is a Markdown converter in JS, which forms the basis for the HTML preview of WMD. They're both made by http://attacklab.net/.

And as far as I know there haven't been any big complaints about both (at least not on the Markdown mailing list). So go for it.

Answer (score 6):

There is one named Showdown and it is currently hosted here: https://github.com/coreyti/showdown

And there is https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js :)

Answer (score 4):

Strapdown.js, which was [recently released](http://strapdownjs.com), "makes it embarrassingly simple to create elegant Markdown documents. No server-side compilation required."

Answer (score 3):

I've not tested this, but here is another option:

[Markdown wysiwyg](http://sourceforge.net/projects/md-wysiwyg/)

Answer (score 3):

The question is even more ancient now but also even more relevant since much of the mentioned code is several years out of date.

However, I did find a few that still seems current:

[Jquery-Markedit](http://tstone.github.com/jquery-markedit/) - This was forked from wmd-edit quite some time ago and refactored to use jQuery. Seems good at first sight.

[EpicEditor](https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor) - is also still maintained, has a flexible parser and, as you can see below, the author is highly responsive (see below). IT seems to have good documentation as well. Sadly not working with IE9.

[MarkdownDeep](http://www.toptensoftware.com/markdowndeep/dingus) is a third option that is still current. The interesting point with this one is support for Markdown Extra. Has a dependency on JQuery (actually you can also implement without JQuery). Based on the .NET version so documentation is more aligned to that than the JS version. This also works with IE9. It is very easy to use (with JQuery) & very simple. No significant development happening with this though as far as I can see.

[js-markdown-extra](https://github.com/tanakahisateru/js-markdown-extra) is a fairly accurate port of the PHP library and is still under maintenance. It supports Markdown Extra of course.

Comment: Live previews work fine with my editor :) open fullscreen as an example or simply run `preview()` on keydown or a timeout. It's built for any kind of customization.

Comment: @OscarGodson thanks for pointing that out +1 for keeping a close eye on things! Is there an example of that in the documentation, I couldn't see it, though I admit I didn't have much time to look. Perhaps I can take another look.

Comment: There's not an example of that specifically no, because most people use the either the toggling or full screen, not their own custom previewer. However, if you give me an example use case I can write up an example for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks Oscar. I am wanting a WIKI that I can use on restricted corporate desktops. I am writing it as an HTA (HTML Application) because that get OS privileges and will run on any Windows desktop. So what I want to do is to keep the WIKI entries in MD files and I want the option to have a live preview, ether underneath the editor or to the right of it when space allows - for your example, underneath would probably be better as the HTML is simpler. Is that enough? Happy to say more.

Comment: So, under the editor is how it works now. Once you click preview it shows the hidden previewer which is updated with what you wrote. Fullscreen does it (sorta) as you type. To make your own previewer you could do something like this: http://jsbin.com/otuyub/edit#javascript,html

Comment: That will put the generated HTML into a new previewer div I made as an example. It should work by simply clicking render and start typing. If you reload the page the previewer div should load an up to date preview.

Comment: Can't get on to jsbin.com just now, it isn't responding. I'll try again later.

Comment: Hi Oscar, I got on but I've only had chance for a quick look. It may take me a few days to get back to it as I'm rather tied up at the moment. I'll update you when I've had another go.    One small think I meant to check. Can I intercept the SAVE function? I need to do a save locally rather than via AJAX.

Comment: Intercept? You can do: `editor.on('save', function(file) { console.log(file.content) })` if thats what you mean. That'll spit out the file contents whenever the file is saved.

Comment: Also, you might want to use `on('update')` instead of save. Save will fire a lot if you have autosave on. Update will only fire when something changes. http://epiceditor.com/#events

Comment: Brill, I'll get to it as soon as I can make some time. Hopefully in the next couple of days.

Comment: OK, I've tried it - one problem, I can't get it to work in Firefox 11. In fact, although your homepage works, a simple example doesn't, nothing gets rendered at all. However, it does work in Chrome. So, to clarify. Neither the exampl in jsbin nor a simple setup works in FF, but your homepage does.

Comment: OK, I take that back. It looks like NoScript is being far too "helpful"! I've turned it off and things seem to be working now.

Comment: Grrr, error with IE9:  "SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'epiceditor': object is null or undefined " "epiceditor.js, line 1135 character 5" also on line 1000. `var files = JSON.parse(localStorage[this.settings.localStorageName]);`

Comment: FYI to anyone reading this: https://github.com/OscarGodson/EpicEditor/issues/137 -- the problem is that it was trying to be run locally and IE9 has security restrictions against using localStorage locally via file:\\\

Answer (score 2):

The question is ancient but hopefully this might help someone. I have just recently published a working version of my own Javascript markdown editor, [uedit](http://amir-hadzic.github.com/uedit/). You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/amir-hadzic/uedit). It works on most browsers (including IE6+) and doesn't depend on any external JS libraries.

Answer (score 2):

After trying with several plugins to solve my own needs of offering a MarkDown seudo-WYSIWYG I ended implementing my own one:

- http://fguillen.github.com/MDMagick/

Maybe is not as powerful as all the solutions commented here but I think that none is as **simple and easy to integrate and customize**.