# How to show README.md in a web page in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, markdown, readme

I hava a laravel project, there is a README.md in the root directory. I can see the render result after pushing to GitHub, but I want to render markdown document in the local development browser.

I am trying two ways:

1. Read file from markdown file
2. convert markdown file to html with something like Webpack

Who can give a demo for this?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35442329/visualizing-readme-md-files-in-my-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Laravel Mix / Webpack solution, convert markdown file to html, and required in Vue.js, then show it with `v-html`.

First add `markdown-loader`

```
yarn add markdown-loader html-loader
```

Add config in `webpack.mix.js`, Laravel Mix can add custom config of Webpack.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.md$/,
      use: ["html-loader", "markdown-loader"],
    }]
  }
});
```

Considering `README.md` is in the root of Project, add a alias in `webpack.mix.js`

```
mix.alias({
  '@': '/resources/js',
  '@root': '/',
});
```

Now we can use a vue component to show the README.md at the root directory.

```
<script>
const readme = require('@root/README.md')
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      readme: ""
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.readme = readme
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="container" ref="container" v-html="readme" />
</template>
```

Comment: How did you come up with this in under an hour

Answer (score 2):

Since the mail blade templates parse markdown, you can use a similar approach to layout.blade.php which uses Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse.

In your template, such as welcome.blade.php, add this:

```
{{ Illuminate\Mail\Markdown::parse(file_get_contents(base_path() . '/README.md')) }}
```