# Markdown to html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, markdown

I actually use TinyMCE (4.8.2) on my application for multiple fields. i automatize fields by json content from JIRA API. BUT... One of the field is already in Markdown from JIRA.

Then i have implemented plugin text_pattern from tinymce to configure the markdown symbol in javascipt. The problem still persist and the text will not changed to html without rewrite the text. I can't find issue, do you ?

```
function initMCEexact(e) {
    tinymce.init({
        mode: "exact",
        theme: "modern",
        plugins: 'textpattern, advlist',
        selector: 'textarea',
        elements: e,
        textpattern_patterns: [
            {start: '_', end: '_', format: 'italic'},
            {start: '*', end: '*', format: 'bold'},
            {start: 'h1. ', format: 'h1'},
            {start: 'h2. ', format: 'h2'},
            {start: 'h3. ', format: 'h3'},
            {start: 'h4. ', format: 'h4'},
            {start: 'h5. ', format: 'h5'},
            {start: 'h6. ', format: 'h6'},
            {start: '# ', cmd: 'InsertOrderedList'},
            {start: '* ', cmd: 'InsertUnorderedList'},
            {start: '*', cmd: 'InsertUnorderedList'},
            {start: '//brb', replacement: 'Be Right Back'}
        ]
    });
}
```

Expecting translation of markdown to HTML automatically.

Answer (score 6):

It might be better if you use a Markdown to HTML converter. I recommend [ShowdownJS](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown). Just add it to your project with `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.0/showdown.min.js"></script>`, and then use this code:

```
var converter = new showdown.Converter();
var text = '# hello, markdown!';
var html = converter.makeHtml(text);
```

Comment: Hello thanks for you're answer, the library is pretty cool but it's not adapted to my problem. In fact this library is maybe too restrictive...

Comment: the values to change are to restrictive, exemple for the library : # heading and in my case : h1. heading

Answer (score 3):

### Really simple and possibly the smallest *JavaScript* *MarkDown* to *HTML* converter

- [drawdown.js at master · adamvleggett/drawdown](https://github.com/adamvleggett/drawdown/blob/master/drawdown.js)

### Detailed list of *JavaScript* *MarkDown* converters

- [jquery - Javascript to convert Markdown/Textile to HTML (and, ideally, back to Markdown/Textile) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319657/javascript-to-convert-markdown-textile-to-html-and-ideally-back-to-markdown-t)