# Rendering Azure DevOps wiki markdown files as HTML

Tags: javascript, azure-devops, markdown

We have a wiki in Azure DevOps and would like to port this to our webbased application to be visible within. (Redirection is not an option: the wiki has to run inside the application.)

Looking at the Azure DevOps wiki HTML, it seems the DevOps wiki markdown is rendered by multiple JS scripts: it-markdown, katex, a script for TOC generation, etc. Has anyone managed to merge al these JS scripts into one to render an Azure DevOps wiki markdown file outside of DevOps environment?

Note that this question is specific to Azure DevOps markdown flavor while [this answer in generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319657/javascript-to-convert-markdown-textile-to-html-and-ideally-back-to-markdown-t) doesn't cover specific features such as LaTeX, table of contents, etc. in markdown!

Answer (score 0):

One possible method would be to use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org). The DevOps Markdown is a bit special, so you'd need to call pandoc with

```
pandoc --from=markdown-space_in_atx_header-blank_before_header \
    --standalone --output OUT.html INPUT.md
```

Comment: I should note that I have no experience with this, but based my answer on info from this thread: https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/c5x7RNrbQ6M/m/UbbYVhCVEQAJ

Comment: Katex doesn't seem to be rendered between `$$`, etc...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you add describe the problem in more detail?