# Markdown parser in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parsing, wysiwyg, markdown

Does anyone know a markdown parser in Javascript ?

PS : Actually, I do this with request to server to parse it, but a client side parser would be better :) .

**Edit :** If there is no one, I will use HTML (with WYSIWYG editor).

Comment: Btw *Showdown* is the first hit if you google for `javascript markdown`.

Comment: (*related*) (second hit on Google ;) ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control

Comment: Yes, I do the Google search too before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Showdown? -

The http://attacklab.net/showdown/ site is defunct.

Showdown is now available on git, here: https://github.com/coreyti/showdown

Comment: No, I would like use it in my website. I would like a javascript function "markdown(text)" whitch return the parsed text. (But Thanks for the answer, I will read his source code).

Comment: @Dorian: It is meant to download the source code and use it in your own site: *Showdown is a JavaScript port of the original Perl version of Markdown. You can get the full source code by clicking on the version number at the bottom of the page.* And in the corner: *Download Showdown v0.9*

Comment: @Dorian: No hard feelings ;) You're welcome.

Comment: This is a dead link. Is the project no longer available?

Answer (score 3):

[markdown-js](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) is awesome.

```
html = markdown.toHTML(someMarkdownText);
```