# ExtJS Create a component like editor of stackoverflow

Tags: extjs, components, textarea

I want to create a component on ExtJS like the editor that have stackoverflow for ask question (only Bold and Emphasis buttons). I think that should be an extension of textarea but i dont know how to select text selected and how to replace with tags+text. Please give me some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: did you consider using the HtmlEditor?

Comment: Ext's HtmlEditor is a good place to start. For more complex rich-text editing, consider TinyMCE and its associated ExtJS extension [link](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Extension:TinyMCE)

Comment: HTMLEditor generate Html Code. I need to add asterisks like stackoverflow editor.

Comment: @richardhell did you manage to create such a markdown editor extension for  ExtJS ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the ability to use asterisks for bullets and such, in that mode StackOverflow's editor uses something called "[Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)".

Here's one example of someone trying to make a markdown-based textarea with preview in Extjs:

[http://www.sencha.com/learn/Extension:Ext.ux.MarkdownEditor](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Extension%3aExt.ux.MarkdownEditor)

If you look around for other Markdown-related editors, you might find some ideas.  If you're instead looking for just an ["Online Rich-Text Editor"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor) there's plenty of those.

---

**UPDATE 29-APR-2014**: There's actually a project you should take a look at.  It's called "StackEdit":

https://stackedit.io

It's an open source initiative to supply a markdown editing component.  Not ExtJS based, but those who find this question may be interested in what they are doing it.

(I discovered it through one of SO's open-source-recruiting sidebar campaigns; advertising *can* be useful, apparently.)

Comment: Ok. Markdown sounds good. But i don't know how download that extension.

Comment: Hm, it does seem to be missing.  But it probably wasn't a whole lot of code to begin with.  There are some client-side and server-side options for processing Markdown, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control

Answer (score 1):

[Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) by John Gruber can be obtained from his site. You could use his documentation as a basis for creating your own plugin for the HtmlEditor.