# GitHub Flavoured Markdown viewer

Tags: javascript, gist

My application needs to show Markdown(syntax similar to `GitHub Flavoured Markdown`) file in a way GitHub Gist. I know, GitHub are using redcarpet package to convert markdown to HTML.

Is there any javascript utiltiy to convert Markdown to HTML?

NOTE: i worked with `showdown` javascript, but i am not satisfied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any good Markdown Javascript library or control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control)

Answer (score 0):

The github API has a service to 'translate' the markdown in raw and GMF mode, the only issue with this is using in cross-domain requests, take a look in http://developer.github.com/v3/markdown/.