# Using jade with wysiwyg markdown to allow users to edit content

Tags: node.js, express, tinymce, wysiwyg, pug

I believe don't re-invent the wheel unless you absolutely have to. So I don't want to start coding away something that has already been coded, or a lot of people are contributing to it already.

I have just recently emigrated to planet Node.js (sorry php/apache), and need to put resources together to bring things up to speed with other languages.

I am using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/) as a server listener, with [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/api.html) as middle-ware, and [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme-contents) js as a template engine.

I would like to use a [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php) like features but instead of the code being the usual ugly HTML `markup`, I would like the code to be the `markdown` and allow **jade** to do its majic. I suppose it more or less like stackoverflow edit (which I am typing in) but maybe a little more advanced UI wise.

So for instance if I click on a button <kbd>**B**</kbd> it should make the selected text bold as you would, with any WYSIWYG editors.

**References**:

- http://nodejs.org/api/
- http://expressjs.com/api.html
- https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#readme-contents
- http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any good Markdown Javascript library or control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134235/is-there-any-good-markdown-javascript-library-or-control)

Comment: It's so not the same, I have asked for Node JS + Jade, solution not a markdown solution, since jade works as a markdown html, I have not come across any solutions for to work gracefully with jade. E.g: If I click on a button `B` on WYSIWYG, the source code should look like `\nstrong my text\n` on database and html is actually `<strong>my text</strong>` on the browser.

Comment: **since jade works as a markdown html** if you mean that they are both a markup language than you are correct. It's a bit of a weird requirement though. You want your editor to use markdown behind the scene but you want to store jade in the database. That means you need to keep converting it back and forward. Why not just store the markdown in the database? Jade has a markdown filter or you can write your own markdown helper in express if you want to show the markup outside of the editor.

Comment: I did say markdown on database,on the comment above... Hence why I didnt want to use lets say ckeditor because they produce raw html as oppose to a mark down on the `source`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use any of the HTML generating WYSIWYG editors, and on "save", allow the HTML to pass to the server where you convert it to Jade syntax before storing it.

You could easily integrate this package, for example, into your Express server:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/html2jade

```
html2jade.convertHtml(html, {}, function (err, jade) {
   // save jade to the DB
});
```

Comment: That is really simple :), I can't believe I didn't think of this at the time :) +1