# How does Stack Overflow formatting works?

Tags: formatting

I just wanted to know that how does this formatting works.I mean I need to enclose my code with `ctrl+k`.How this works programmatically in Java?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Java has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ok so is it that its a functionality of some scripting language?I need to implement the same thing in java.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Stack Overflow site itself, and can no longer be migrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/135155/78845) by some guy called ["Jeff Atwood"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) (who seems to know what he's talking about) suggests that you should take a look here: https://code.google.com/p/pagedown/

From that site:

> PageDown is the version of Attacklab's Showdown and WMD as used on Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites.
>
> It includes a converter that turns Markdown into HTML, a Markdown editor with realtime preview of the generated HTML, and a few useful plugins, e.g. for sanitizing the generated HTML according to a whitelist of allowed tags.
>
> The Markdown converter can be used both in the browser (usually in conjunction with the editor, to display a real time preview), and on the server using Node.JS.